# Most efficient to find items in multiple list POCO and merge then in master list

Tags: c#, .net, list, optimization, list-comparison

I have a C# class, Lets call it `Item` class. `Item` class have following properties.

```
 Name
 Region
 Value
```

I have 4 list containing multiple object of type `item`. One of the list is master list.

Following are content of **MasterList**

```
Name    Region       Value
A       Global       10
B       Global       20
C       Global       30
D       Global       40
E       Global       50
F       Global       60
G       Global       70
H       Global       80
I       Global       90
J       Global       100
```

Following are content of **USAList**

```
Name    Region       Value
G       USA          50
H       USA          50
I       USA          50
J       USA          50
A       USA          50
```

Following are content of **UKList**

```
Name    Region       Value
A       UK          20
B       UK          20
C       UK          20
D       UK          20
F       UK          20
```

Following are content of **EUList**

```
Name    Region       Value
A       EU          30
B       EU          30
D       EK          30
G       EK          30
I       EK          30
```

Any list can have any number of items. Master list will have all the items. An item can appear only once in a list. Items may or may not be sorted (by name) in the list.

I want to find items from all the lists, assuming master list have all the items. I need to find items by name & create a new list which should look like this.

```
Name   GlobalValue     USAValue      UKValue      EUValue
A      10              50             20             30
B      20                             20             30 
C      30                             20
D      40                             20             30
E      50
F      60                             20
G      70              50                            30
H      80              50 
I      90              50                            30
J      100             50
```

I know I can create a new class which will have following properties.

```
Name, GlobalValue, USAValue, UKValue, EUValue
```

Then I can start a loop to go over master list & inside this loop, I will run 3 more loops. One for USAList, one for UKList & one for EUList. Then I ill try to find item by name and I will create the new list.

But I want to know the most efficient way to get the desired result.

DEMO CLASS & LIST

```
public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

LIST

```
List<Item> MasterList = new List<Item>();
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "A", Region = "Global", Value = "10"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "B", Region = "Global", Value = "20"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "C", Region = "Global", Value = "30"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "D", Region = "Global", Value = "40"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "E", Region = "Global", Value = "50"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "F", Region = "Global", Value = "60"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "G", Region = "Global", Value = "70"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "H", Region = "Global", Value = "80"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "I", Region = "Global", Value = "90"});
            MasterList.Add(new Item {Name = "J", Region = "Global", Value = "100"});

            List<Item> USAList = new List<Item>();
            USAList.Add(new Item { Name = "G", Region = "USA", Value = "50" });
            USAList.Add(new Item { Name = "H", Region = "USA", Value = "50" });
            USAList.Add(new Item { Name = "I", Region = "USA", Value = "50" });
            USAList.Add(new Item { Name = "J", Region = "USA", Value = "50" });
            USAList.Add(new Item { Name = "A", Region = "USA", Value = "40" });

            List<Item> UkList = new List<Item>();
            UkList.Add(new Item { Name = "A", Region = "UK", Value = "20" });
            UkList.Add(new Item { Name = "B", Region = "UK", Value = "20" });
            UkList.Add(new Item { Name = "C", Region = "UK", Value = "20" });
            UkList.Add(new Item { Name = "D", Region = "UK", Value = "20" });
            UkList.Add(new Item { Name = "F", Region = "UK", Value = "20" });

            List<Item> EUList = new List<Item>();
            EUList.Add(new Item { Name = "A", Region = "EU", Value = "30" });
            EUList.Add(new Item { Name = "B", Region = "EU", Value = "30" });
            EUList.Add(new Item { Name = "G", Region = "EU", Value = "30" });
            EUList.Add(new Item { Name = "G", Region = "EU", Value = "30" });
            EUList.Add(new Item { Name = "I", Region = "EU", Value = "30" });
```

Comment: Any reason for down vote ?

Comment: Can't speak for the downvoter, but maybe you should show the existing code that you have which populates the new list. As it stands it looks like you could be asking us to write it for you. And also can you define what you mean by "most efficient"?

Comment: @stuartd: Thanks . I will update question.

Comment: If you want to be able to look up an item by name quickly in a collection, consider using `Dictionary<string, Item>` collections instead of lists. Obviously, the key would be the name of the item.

Comment: What do you understand when you say "efficient"? Time, Space, ...? Can this Masterlist have items that are not in any other list? From what I see there is a missing list "Global" and the overall masterlist should be empty.

Comment: @MareInfinitus: By efficient I mean, performance and time. We cannot have a situation where masterlist has a item which is not present in other list

Answer (score 1):

In the example code you provided, you add all items to masterlist instead of the other lists, but coincidentally, that might be the most effective way: concatenating the list and using a `GroupBy` instead of multiple joins:

```
    var list = (from i in MasterList.Concat(USAList).Concat(UkList).Concat(EUList) //concat all lists
            group i by i.Name into g //primary group by on Name
            let d = (IDictionary)g.GroupBy(si=>si.Region).ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr=> gr.Sum(v=>int.Parse(v.Value))) //create a dictionary of regions with the sums as values
            select new {Name = g.Key, GlobalValue = d["Global"], USAValue = d["USA"],  UKValue = d["UK"],   EUValue = d["EU"]}).ToList();
```

Instead of the separate fields, you could add the values dictionary itself.
Also note the cast to `(IDictionary)` . The implementation of the 'IDictionary' index behaves different than on the direct index of the generic index: the latter throws an exception for an index not in the dictionary.

For testing: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j9vite)

Comment: Thanks Robert Verpalen :) Voting up for amazing answer but waiting to see if there is a more efficient way to get the desired result before marking this as answer !!

Comment: Can you please explain what are you doing with this statement   `let d = (IDictionary)g.GroupBy(si=>si.Region).ToDictionary(gr => gr.Key, gr=> gr.Sum(v=>int.Parse(v.Value))) //create a dictionary of regions with the sums as values`

Comment: Sure :) `let` is a way to declare an intermediate value in query syntax, so in this case `d` is declared. `g` is a group of names, created in the line above it. So for each name, 'g' contains all `Item`s. In this line those name groups are grouped by region. During execution that means a group of a single name is grouped into its regions. From that group, a dictionary is created, for each key (region), having as value the sum of all `Item`-values. All in all, at the end, d contains a dictionary of all regions and the amount for the `Name` being iterated